# Can we pass the argument in SQL query while working with pandas dataframe, python

Tags: python-3.x

I have to program for calculating the 'Date Anomalies' for number of contacts per client, number of contracts varies per client. With the following 3 steps I am calculating the Date Anomalies correctly for each contact and at last appending all dataframes and writing it into excel file with sheet wise(as per contract) and one consolidated sheet of all contracts.
**Here is the code:**
Step1:  # Connecting to Database

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=XXXXXXXX;'
                      'Database=XXXXXXX;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

Step 2: sql_query = pd.read_sql_query("Select DISTINCT  ContractName , clientcode, TypeOfFile (CASE WHEN SentToBBDate > BBLoadedDate then 'ERROR - SENT DATE GREATER THAN LOAD DATE' WHEN ReceivedDate > SentToBBDate then 'ERROR - RECEIVED DATE GREATER THAN SENT DATE'  WHEN ReceivedDate is NULL then 'ERROR - FILE NOT RECEIVED' ELSE 'NORMAL' END) AS Error_Message from DataDashboard Where  **ContractName like '%***%**' AND  ClientCode LIKE '%AAA%' Order by TypeOfFile", conn)
first = sql_query.to_csv("firstDashboard.csv")


Step 3:
first= pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\pd\\Desktop\\firstDashboard.csv")
first = Cigna.iloc[: , 1:]
first.drop(first[(first['ERROR_MESSAGE'] == 'NORMAL')].index, inplace=True)
first.to_excel("first_DateReport.xlsx", index=False)
```

Step 2& 3 I repeat for each contract in same Notebook(Jupyter). And append all the dataframes and writing the result into excel file contract wise in different sheets in one excel file.
**Here is the Code**

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\pd\\Desktop\\Consolidated_DateReport.xlsx")
sheets_in_writer=['Conso_DateReport', 'First_DateReport','Second_DateReport']
data_frame_for_writer=[Appenddf,First, Second]

for i,j in zip(data_frame_for_writer,sheets_in_writer):
    i.to_excel(writer,j,index=False)


### Assign WorkBook
workbook=writer.book
# Add a header format
header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'size':11,
                                                      'valign': 'top','fg_color': '#c7e7ff','border': 1})


for worksheet in writer.sheets.values():
            row_count = len(df.index)
            column_count = len(df.columns)
            
### Apply same format on each sheet being saved
for i,j in zip(data_frame_for_writer,sheets_in_writer):
    for col_num, value in enumerate(i.columns.values):
        writer.sheets[j].write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
        writer.sheets[j].freeze_panes(1,0)
        writer.sheets[j].autofilter(0, 0, row_count-1, column_count-2) 
        writer.sheets[j].set_column(0, 7 - 1, 25)
        
writer.save()
```

How do I use the loop/function to pass on the values in Step2 and 3 and avoid writing same code number of times(11 times). In step2 ContractName should get change in SQL query(Where ContractNmae like '%AAA%) And in step3 it should get change such as second then third upto 11.
Any help will be appreciated.